# Babel codemod to transform require statements

Tags: javascript, babel.js

I'm starting to explore the world of ASTs and codemods. As such my first foray is a simple transform to move statements like `let fs = require('fs')` to `const fs = require('fs')`.

```
const declaratorKinds = { let: null, var: null }

export default function(babel) {
 const { types: t } = babel

 return {
   visitor: {
     VariableDeclaration(path) {
       if (!(path.node.kind in declaratorKinds)) { return }

       const d = path.node.declarations[0]

       if (!(
         d.init
         && d.init.callee
         && d.init.callee.name === 'require')) { return }

       path.replaceWith(
         t.VariableDeclaration('const', path.node.declarations)
       )
     }
   }
 }
}
```

Here's a live [ast explorer](https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/e4779b3fccd2bb04906647cb9086eefd/latest) version.

I'm a newbie here so i'm interested in any feedback, but I'd particuarly like to know about:

1. Is `VariableDeclarator` the best node type to base this transform on?
2. Is there a way I could better filter for `require` declarations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem with this code that jumps out is `declaratorKinds = { let: null, var: null }` for use with `path.node.kind in declaratorKinds`. It would be much better to just use an array or set.

```
const declaratorKinds = ['let', 'var']
...
if (declaratorKinds.includes(path.node.kind))
```

As far as I can tell `VariableDeclaration` is the best way to handle this, I have no experience with babel transforms, so I may be missing something.

Bugs:

1. `var fs = require('fs'), temp;` will be transformed into `const fs = require('fs'), temp;` which will throw a syntax error.
2. `var temp = 1, fs = require('fs')` will not be transformed.

A better solution would be to check each `VariableDeclarator` item in `path.node.declarations`, this could look something like the following. (Note that this rewrites multiple simultaneous declarations into separate declarations - the style I prefer)

```
export default function({types}) {  
  return {
    visitor: {
      VariableDeclaration(path) {
        const { kind, declarations } = path.node

        if (!['let', 'var'].includes(kind)) {
          return
        }

        const requireDeclarations = declarations.filter(d => {
          return d.init && d.init.callee && d.init.callee.name == 'require'
        })
        const otherDeclarations = declarations.filter(d => !requireDeclarations.includes(d))

        if (requireDeclarations.length) {
          path.replaceWithMultiple([
            ...requireDeclarations.map(d => types.VariableDeclaration('const', [d])),
            ...otherDeclarations.map(d => types.VariableDeclaration(kind, [d])),
          ])
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Demo [here](https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/9b5992419e6c2d049d21dc4b0bdd0527/6f49486bac34dd364f91a9d7b2770ab93bc7e38c) (forked from your demo)

Comment: Ah great point on bug 2). My codebase doesn't use that style but I know it's popular in the node community.

Comment: As for `includes` versus `in` `in` is much faster in a [very superficial benchmark](https://jsperf.com/checking-for-key-presence) (and `Set.has`). I'm not a fan of micro optimizations but for parsing code that could be used on codebases I think it's a reasonable (and not unreadable) choice. What do you think?

Comment: I don't find the `in` statement too unreadable, but the `declaratorKinds ` declaration looks incredibly wrong to me. If you are really worried about speed,  I believe`(path.node.kind === 'var' || path.node.kind === 'let')`would be a better choice.